# I can't find where to upload the files or make sure the code works

Tags: python, html, flask

I uploaded several files using the following codes. But I don't know how to call and use those files. Or where are these files stored?

In the following code snippet, I request the user to upload a file and I want to read those files after converting them to .csv format and save the information on a chart. But I don't know where my files are saved and I can't find the folder path.

```
from time import time
from xml.dom.minidom import DocumentType
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import os 
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename # is explained a little bit later

upload_folder = '/path/to/the/uploads'   #is where we will store the uploaded files
allowed_extensions = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'} # is the set of allowed file extensions
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['upload_folder'] = upload_folder

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
    return
```

HTML FORM :
I assume that there is no connection between these two pieces of code. How can I make sure that the connection is established?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Headers">
        <h1> Upload File </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><input type="file" name="file"></p> 
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line is where the file is saved

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Therefore, you are saving the file to whatever this path is

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
```

Unless you are hiding the name of your file for the purpose of the question you currently have this set as `'/path/to/the/uploads'`  which will not work, you need to set it as an actual path in your directory, I assume you copied this from somewhere and forgot to change it.

If you create a folder called `uploads` in your root directory then you could change it to

`upload_folder = '/uploads'`

The the file will be uploaded into that folder. With Flask it is common to have a folder called static for storing things like uploads. If you have that then you could change it to  `upload_folder = '/static/uploads'` , but the idea is the same.

Comment: isn't `upload_folder = '/path/to/the/uploads'` where you set this? replace `'/path/to/the/uploads` with a real folder at the root of your project.

Comment: My bad, I hadn't read the beginning properly, I have now corrected my answer, thanks for that.